# Is there a login theme like mac for my ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, login, themes, downloads

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts and I just want a link to a website which has this kind of login theme for ubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, from [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=make+ubuntu+login+screen+look+like+mac&oq=make+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i57j69i60l2j69i59.1017j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=125&ie=UTF-8) google search I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Frf3QlZ_gw) video and then [this](https://github.com/Wattos/LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme) github page with good instructions.

Please do research before asking here.

Also, [this](http://technopyrate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/make-linux-mint-ubuntu-look-like-mac-os.html) might help, as might [this](http://www.geekersmagazine.com/how-to-make-ubuntu-look-like-Mac-os-x/).

However, if you want it identical, why not [buy a mac](http://apple.com/mac)? They're different OSs, and while Ubuntu/Linux is highly customisable, there are some things it isn't built for. The login screen looks nice as it is, and works. Do you have a specific reason for requiring it look identical to a mac?

Comment: Already tried this. I want a login screen like in the picture.

Comment: So you want it to be exactly the same? I would suggest you buy a Mac - http://www.apple.com/mac/. I think the github page is as good as you will get.